# mail function or PHPMailer not working

Tags: php

``I have a wordpress installed on my Server, everything works fine, I tried to add a contact form on the template using the PHP mail() function, 
It works well on a remote hosting server, but when i tried to transfer the same code that successfully worked on a hosting server to my work's local server, It doesn't send any email.
What could be wrong with the server? my code to process form is:

Comment: the code is....... .....  ... ??  not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SMTP server on the server working correctly? You can test this in windows using telnet:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323350

You should also try writing and running a small script that only calls the php mail function, independ of wordpress.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You can read this as a reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You could also try PEAR Pacakage. Download it from here : http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Answer (score 0):

Using PEAR for email is better choice.
One of the search results from google - http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm